# Как получить координаты коллайдера?

Tags: unity3d

Мне нужно сделать так, что бы при входе в объект с триггером, другой объект перемещался к центру коллайдера этого триггера, пробовал разные методы, но все они переносят объект не к коллайдеру триггера, а к объекту на который присоединён триггер. Пробовал методы перемещения к:

1. other.transform.position (Название коллайдера триггера other)
2. transform.position
3. transform.GetComponent().transform.position

Искал на разных формуах, но нигде не смог найти решения, как можно это осуществить?

Comment: `transform.position+collider.Center`

Answer (score 1):

`other` в `OnTriggerEnter` это и так коллайдер. Нужно просто получить координаты его центра, например:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
  Debug.Log(other.bounds.center);
}
```